# Displaying MySQL data into HTML table (clearly explained)

Tags: php, data-structures, mysql

Ok, I have an app as described in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623105/good-database-structure-for-a-new-web-app

I've prepared a scenario to make my question as clear as possible:

```
Users table:
    +----------+-----------------+
    | user_id  | email           |
    +----------+-----------------+
    | user_1   | user1@email.com |
    | user_2   | user2@email.com |
    | user_3   | user3@email.com |
    | user_4   | user4@email.com |
    +----------+-----------------+
```

*Notice user_3 and user_4 do not have their own domains

```
Domains table:
    +-----------+------------+
    | owner_id  | domain     |
    +-----------+------------+
    | user_1    | dom-1.com  | 
    | user_1    | dom-2.com  |
    | user_2    | dom-3.com  |
    +------------------------+
```

The table below, shows who is a user of a domain and who the owner is:

```
User-Domain table:
    +----------+-------------+-----------+
    | user_id  | domain      | owner_id  |
    +------------------------+-----------+
    | user_1   | dom-1.com   | user_1    |
    | user_1   | dom-2.com   | user_1    |
    | user_2   | dom-3.com   | user_2    |
    | user_3   | dom-1.com   | user_1    |
    | user_3   | dom-2.com   | user_1    |
    | user_4   | dom-1.com   | user_1    |
    +------------------------+-----------+
```

**My question is, how do I output a list of each user who is using a given user's domain, in the following format?**

For example (the following is an HTML table):

```
List of users who are using User_1's domains (HTML TABLE):
        +-------------------+-----------------------+
        | Email             | domains               |
        +-------------------+-----------------------+
        | user3@email.com   | dom-1.com, dom-2.com  |
        | user4@email.com   | dom-1.com             |
        +-------------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should give you the results. Displaying a HTML table from it should be easy enough.

```
SELECT
   u.email,
   group_concat(d.domain SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM
   domains d
   JOIN user_domain ud ON d.domain=ud.domain AND d.owner_id=ud.owner_id AND d.owner_id!=ud.user_id
   JOIN users u on ud.user_id=u.user_id
WHERE d.owner_id='user_1'
GROUP BY u.email
```

You basically select all domains owned by 'user_1', then all user_ids for these domains, and then all users for these user_ids. After that, you group the results by the user's email and concatenate all domain names the user is using.

Comment: Lukas, I tried it and I get an error ...
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ANS d.owner_id=ud.owner_id LEFT JOIN users u on ud.user_id=u.user_id WHERE' at line 6

Comment: In fact it does. It seems to return any user who is a user of a domain, and of course each owner is also a user as shown in the User_Domain table.

Comment: I tested the new query and now I get unusual results. It still returns the owner, but this time, the owner's email is NULL and if another user is using a domain, it is not listed for the owner. I don't know if it makes sense but basically this result is worse.

Comment: Well, I could filter out the row where email is NULL but I don't think this is what you expected either.

Comment: Just change LEFT JOIN to JOIN. I initially misunderstood the query and I thought you want a list of domains an all their users, while you wanted a list of users and all their domains.

Comment: That did it, and that has to be one of the most complex sql queries I've ever used. I've lots to learn. Thanks a bunch Lukas ;)